# Hibernate criteria between two days

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to get number of rows between two dates. 
First date is today, second one is 15 days ago.

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Order.class);
            Calendar c15DaysAgo = Calendar.getInstance(); // 15 days ago
            c15DaysAgo.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -15);

            Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance(); // today
            today.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 0);

            criteria.add(Expression.between("orderTime", today, c15DaysAgo));
            totalCount = (Integer) criteria.setProjection(Projections.rowCount()).uniqueResult();
```

I'm getting this exception :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.GregorianCalendar cannot be cast to java.util.Date
    at org.hibernate.type.TimestampType.toString(TimestampType.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeToString(NullableType.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeSet(NullableType.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeSet(NullableType.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.bindPositionalParameters(Loader.java:1707)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.bindParameterValues(Loader.java:1678)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1563)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:673)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2220)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2104)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2099)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1569)
    at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:283)
    at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.uniqueResult(CriteriaImpl.java:305)
```

Is there some way I can do count?

Comment: Remember to round(truncate/ceiling) the Date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need today.getTime().  Hibernate wants a Date, not a Calendar...

Comment: thank you paul its working when using both get dates but not producing the correct results

Comment: @Gandalf StormCrow Are the dates correct (e.g., rounded as lschin suggested)?  Does it look like hibernate is producing the right sql now?