# Replication event listeners in AEM Class cast exception

Tags: maven, aem

I am trying to create a `ReplicationEventListener` for `AEM 6.1` with the following code but It gives a `classcast exception` at 
line `ReplicationAction action = ReplicationAction)ReplicationAction.fromEvent(event);`

The exception is

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.GregorianCalendar cannot be cast to java.util.Date
    at com.day.cq.replication.ReplicationEvent.fromEvent(ReplicationEvent.java:221)
    at com.adobe.cq.listeners.ReplicationEventListener.handleEvent(ReplicationEventListener.java:30)
    at org.apache.felix.eventadmin.impl.handler.EventHandlerProxy.sendEvent(EventHandlerProxy.java:415)
    at org.apache.felix.eventadmin.impl.tasks.SyncDeliverTasks.execute(SyncDeliverTasks.java:118)
    at org.apache.felix.eventadmin.impl.tasks.AsyncDeliverTasks$TaskExecuter.run(AsyncDeliverTasks.java:159)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

My JAVA class is

```
package com.adobe.cq.listeners;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Component;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Property;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Service;
import org.osgi.service.event.Event;
import org.osgi.service.event.EventHandler;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import com.day.cq.replication.ReplicationAction;

@Component
@Service()
@Property(name = "event.topics", value = { ReplicationAction.EVENT_TOPIC })
public class ReplicationEventListener implements EventHandler{
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ReplicationEventListener.class);


public void handleEvent(Event event) {

    String n[] = event.getPropertyNames();
    log.info("Event properties: ");

    for (String s : n) {

        log.info(s + " = " + event.getProperty(s));
    }

    ReplicationAction action = (ReplicationAction) ReplicationAction.fromEvent(event);

    if (action != null) {

        log.info("Replication action {} occured on {} ", action.getType()
                .name(), action.getPath());



    }



}
    }
```

My parent POM

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <!-- ====================================================================== -->
        <!-- P A R E N T P R O J E C T D E S C R I P T I O N -->
        <!-- ====================================================================== -->

        <groupId>com.adobe.cq</groupId>
        <artifactId>sample</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>pom</packaging>

        <name>My Project - Reactor Project</name>
        <description>Maven Multimodule project for My Project.</description>

        <prerequisites>
            <maven>3.0.2</maven>
        </prerequisites>

        <!-- ====================================================================== -->
        <!-- P R O P E R T I E S -->
        <!-- ====================================================================== -->
        <properties>
            <crx.host>localhost</crx.host>
            <crx.port>4502</crx.port>
            <crx.username>admin</crx.username>
            <crx.password>admin</crx.password>
            <publish.crx.host>localhost</publish.crx.host>
            <publish.crx.port>4503</publish.crx.port>
            <publish.crx.username>admin</publish.crx.username>
            <publish.crx.password>admin</publish.crx.password>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        </properties>

        <dependencyManagement>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
                    <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
                    <version>4.2.0</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
                    <artifactId>org.osgi.compendium</artifactId>
                    <version>4.2.0</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                    <artifactId>org.apache.felix.scr.annotations</artifactId>
                    <version>1.6.0</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>biz.aQute</groupId>
                    <artifactId>bndlib</artifactId>
                    <version>1.43.0</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                    <version>1.5.10</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.jcr</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jcr</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
                    <artifactId>org.apache.sling.api</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2.0</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
                    <artifactId>org.apache.sling.jcr.api</artifactId>


       <version>2.1.0</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.8.1</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
  <groupId>com.day.cq</groupId>
  <artifactId>cq-replication</artifactId>
  <version>5.0.6</version>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.sling.models.api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
      </dependency>

            <dependency>
    <groupId>com.day.cq</groupId>

       <artifactId>cq-mailer</artifactId>

       <version>5.6.2</version>

        <scope>provided</scope>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-email</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>


        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <!--
        Inclusion of repositories in POMs is controversial, to say the least.
        It would be best if you proxied the Adobe repository using a Maven
        Repository Manager. Once you do that, remove these sections.
     -->
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>adobe</id>
            <name>Adobe Public Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>adobe</id>
            <name>Adobe Public Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-scr-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.7.4</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.7</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.7</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.14.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.9</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-sling-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <username>${crx.username}</username>
                        <password>${crx.password}</password>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.day.jcr.vault</groupId>
                    <artifactId>content-package-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>0.0.20</version>
                    <extensions>true</extensions>
                    <configuration>
                        <failOnError>true</failOnError>
                        <username>${crx.username}</username>
                        <password>${crx.password}</password>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse
                    m2e settings only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>
                                            org.apache.felix
                                        </groupId>
                                        <artifactId>
                                            maven-scr-plugin
                                        </artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>
                                            [1.0.0,)
                                        </versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>scr</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore/>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>autoInstallBundle</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-sling-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>install-bundle</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>install</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
  <modules>
    <module>bundle</module>
    <module>content</module>
  </modules>
</project>
```

My Bundle POM is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd ">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <!-- ====================================================================== -->
    <!-- P A R E N T P R O J E C T D E S C R I P T I O N -->
    <!-- ====================================================================== -->
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.adobe.cq</groupId>
        <artifactId>sample</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <!-- ====================================================================== -->
    <!-- P R O J E C T D E S C R I P T I O N -->
    <!-- ====================================================================== -->

    <artifactId>sample-bundle</artifactId>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>
    <name>My Project Bundle</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.compendium</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.felix.scr.annotations</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>biz.aQute</groupId>
            <artifactId>bndlib</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.jcr</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcr</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.sling.api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.sling.jcr.api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.sling.models.api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
  <groupId>com.day.cq</groupId>
  <artifactId>cq-replication</artifactId>

</dependency>

        <dependency>
    <groupId>com.day.cq</groupId>

       <artifactId>cq-mailer</artifactId>



        <scope>provided</scope>

        </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.day.cq</groupId>

       <artifactId>cq-mailer</artifactId>



        <scope>provided</scope>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-email</artifactId>

</dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <!-- ====================================================================== -->
    <!-- B U I L D D E F I N I T I O N -->
    <!-- ====================================================================== -->
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-scr-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-scr-descriptor</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>scr</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                    <Sling-Model-Packages>com.adobe.cq.models</Sling-Model-Packages>
                        <Bundle-SymbolicName>com.adobe.cq.sample-bundle</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                        <Embed-Dependency>*;scope=compile|runtime</Embed-Dependency>
                        <!--<Embed-Directory>OSGI-INF/lib</Embed-Directory>
                        <Embed-Transitive>true</Embed-Transitive>
                        -->
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-sling-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <slingUrl>http://${crx.host}:${crx.port}/apps/sampleProject/install</slingUrl>
                    <usePut>true</usePut>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludePackageNames>
                        *.impl
                    </excludePackageNames>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

Any help is appreciated
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Would you please add ReplicationEvent.java class? Then it will be helpful to give answer. @Shreya

Comment: @SkyWalker  I have already added ReplicationEventListener class.Please see above its the first code I have added.

Comment: I am asking to provide ReplicationEvent.java class. If possible, update your question and give the java code

Comment: ReplicationEventListener class has no calendar related info. So please provide ReplicationEvent.java class

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972528/hibernate-criteria-between-two-days just follow the answer on your code

Comment: Can you pls print the value and type of object for `event.getProperty("modificationDate")` before the line where you're getting the `ClassCastException`.

Comment: @Abhishek The value is  com.adobe.cq.listeners.ReplicationEventListener modificationDate = java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1461304186511,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Asia/Calcutta",offset=19800000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=6,lastRule=null],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2016,MONTH=3,WEEK_OF_YEAR=17,WEEK_OF_MONTH=4,DAY_OF_MONTH=22,DAY_OF_YEAR=113,DAY_OF_WEEK=6,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=4,AM_PM=0,HOUR=11,HOUR_OF_DAY=11,MINUTE=19,SECOND=46,MILLISECOND=511,ZONE_OFFSET=19800000,DST_OFFSET=0]

Comment: @SkyWalker I have not added ReplicationEvent.java .This seems to be a  built in class

Comment: @ShreyaVerma That exception trace and your code are a mismatch. Your code is calling `ReplicationAction.fromEvent` while the exception trace is saying your code is calling `ReplicationEvent.fromEvent`. Which one is correct ?. Also the scope of the `cq-replication` jar should be provided.

Comment: @Abhishek I tried installing OSGI bundle in a fresh AEM instance.Also added scope as provided in Bundle POM.The Exception I am facing now is  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.day.cq.replication.ReplicationAction.fromEvent(Lorg/osgi/service/event/Event;)Lcom/day/cq/replication/ReplicationEvent;
 at com.adobe.cq.listeners.ReplicationEventListener.handleEvent(ReplicationEventListener.java:30)

Comment: I noticed that ReplicationAction.fromEvent(event) returns ReplicationEvent and not ReplicationAction that is the reason I have to cast ReplicationAction action = (ReplicationAction)ReplicationAction.fromEvent(event);

Comment: Looks like the problem with the version of the jar that you're using. Can you update the version in the pom to latest ? You can find the versions here https://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public/com/day/cq/cq-replication/

Comment: @Abhishek  Thanks a lot.The problem was with the version.I updated version and it started working

Comment: cool. Adding this as the answer so that the question can be marked accepted for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The runtime APIs for `cq-replication` package are not matching to what you're using at compile time. You need to update the version of this jar to the latest in your `pom.xml`. Also since this is a container provided library, you should have this as a `provided` dependency.

The latest versions of various libraries can be found in Adobe's [public nexus repository](https://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public/).